# EditText.setError() on single line

Tags: java, android

I have a question about `EditText.setError()`.

I have an EditText :

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/sc_num"
                style="@style/textLabel"
                android:text="@string/scnum"
                android:layout_below="@+id/creditCard"/>
<EditText android:id="@+id/credit"              
android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
android:layout_below="@+id/sc_num"
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/state"/>
```

I want to display the error message "*please enter a valid security code*"
using the `setError()` method.

When I run the app I'm getting an error displayed in multiple lines as shown in the picture

[image: security code Edit text]

What would I do to display this error in single line?

Comment: final EditText cardSCNoField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.credit);
String cardSCNoString = cardSCNoField.getText().toString().trim();
cardSCNoField.setError("The Security code no is not valid please enter a valid code.");

Comment: give some width to edittext and it will display correctly like fill_parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `android:scrollHorizontally="true"`.

**EDIT:**
Use `android:SingleLine="true"`.

Comment: Just so you know, singleLine is deprecated.

Comment: @hemanth kumar Last time try out: android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="50dip" 

working for me...