# set width of EditText.setError() popup Android

Tags: android, android-layout

What is the EditText.setError() popup width based on?

My xml:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/link_existing_project_data"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:hint="@string/link_existing_project_hint"
    android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:paddingRight="30dp"
    android:textSize="20dp" />
```

and what I get:

[image: setError() width]

How can I get it to fill the full width therefore displaying on a single line?

Is it not based on the EditText width?

Thanks

Comment: Look here. It seems they solved the problem. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924576/edittext-seterror-in-single-line

Comment: @JakubKinst I tried that, it is not working